# Animate the the text in a textview (swift3)

Tags: ios, animation, button, swift3, textview

I am looking for the text to be scroll all the way down to the bottom that is it. Just like you would see in movie credits. I do not want to move the x, y location of the textview just the text inside from top to bottom.

```
   import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var text: UITextView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func play(_ sender: Any) {
}


}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code is totally irrelevant. Please delete it from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `UIScrollView` and scroll a `UILabel` with the text in it.

You can use standard `UIView` animation with timing and optionally animation curve and set the `contentOffset` inside the closure.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 10.0) { // 10 seconds
   scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: maxDesiredScrollPosition)
}
```